# Wondering about the feasibility of writing a launcher extension for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm a very heavy [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) and [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) user and I was wondering how feasible it would be to write something similar as an extension for VS(2010 and higher) so that program functionality could be accessed by typing the first few letters and then choosing item(s) from a dropdown menu of suggestions which would update as one typed.

I'm a C#/Java guy but I have no experience of writing VS extensions. I'd be grateful if anyone could offer some pointers I could follow to get things moving or conversely pooh-pooh and pour cold water on my idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

VS has a built in feature for searching for types, Ctrl+, - which gives you a drop down for matching types. It also does camel case too which is frickin awesome. So if you want to find class `SomeStupidClassNameUsingCamelCaseNamingConvention`, you can just hit ctrl+shift+t and type SSCN and it will find your type.

If you have Resharper installed it has the same functionality with Ctrl+Shift+T, but tbh I'm not quite sure what the diffrence is!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm familiar with the  Ctrl  +  ,  shortcut. I'm looking for a launcher-style control to give me access to VS functions, especially ones with lengthy 'shortcuts' like `Format Document` (currently assigned to  Ctrl + K , Ctrl + D).

Comment: ahh I see, I misunderstood, sorry I can't be of any help with what you need

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 has exactly what you're asking for, on the `Ctrl+Q` shortcut.

Comment: So it does, thanks. Unfortunately, like (imho) the rest of the new GUI it's completely wrong from a usability viewpoint - tucked way up on the top menu. I like how the launchers I used appear bang in the centre of the screen floating 'above' all other windows. Do you think it would be possible to style and position it differently?

Comment: @5arx: Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks v.much. I'll accept your answer if nothing else turns up (I suspect it won't)